# Service to store dynamic IPs

Tags: dynamic, ip, server

I'm looking for a service that would allow me to connect 2 computers with dynamics IPs.

There is the use case of the ideal service:

Client A wants to exchange with Client B using S server, with a known IP.

1. B connects to S and gives its current IP (global or local) and a UID
2. S stores B's IP and B's UID
3. A connects to S and ask for IP of B client using its UID (known)
4. S looks for UID and return B's IP
5. A receives B's IP

I need that because I don't know the computers' IP defore run time.
Do you know something that would solve this ? Ideally, it would work simply with my java client-server I'm curently developing, where the server should be found by the client.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you are describing is exactly how Teamviewer remote control service is working. This way, you circumvent any NAT or firewall issues - neither A nor B need to open ports for forwarding, both connections are outward. See www.teamviewer.de for more details (note: no affiliation to this company, just a user).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already knew this was something used by Skype, for exemple. I am not looking for a software to take remote control, I am just asking if you know one service that would allow me to exchange IPs for free. Ideally, it would work simply with my java client-server I'm curently developing.

Comment: No, sorry, not that I know of. You might have to set up that service yourself (and promote it to charge other users for it).